# How to move differentation before the integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have quite a lot expressions that need to be integrated after switching the integral sign with differentiation operator. The additional problem is that the bounds are dependent to one of the variables. So I need to use:

$\int_{a(y)} ^{b(y)} {\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_{a(y)} ^{b(y)} f(x,y) dx- \frac{db}{dy}f(x=b,y)+\frac{da}{dy}f(x=a,y)$

How do I achieve this in *Mathematica*? For now *Mathematica* just writes the output

```
Integrate[D[f[x, y], y], {x, a[y], b[y]}]
```

in the symbolic form. How do I workaround this? Of course I can write my own function, but I wonder if *Mathematica* has some built in functionality I require.

Comment: Does a replacement rule work? `(your expression) /. HoldPattern[Integrate[D[e_, y_], {x_,a_,b_}]]:>D[Integrate[e,{x,a,b}],y]-D[b,y](e/.x->b)+D[a,y](e/.x->a)`

Comment: Probably it does. I just wondered if there is some kind of function implementing this theorem.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant to your question,but Mma does use the Leibniz rule: when you evaluate `D[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, a[y], b[y]}], y]` you get `Integrate[Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y], {x, a[y], b[y]}] - 
  f[a[y], y]*Derivative[1][a][y] + f[b[y], y]*Derivative[1][b][y]`.

Comment: Well, it looks like my doesn't :] Or better... sometimes it does tometimes it doesn't <?> Ok, now I get it, it does so only in one direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
g[y_] := Inactivate[Integrate][f[x, y], {x, a[y], b[y]}];
```

Then its derivative:

```
D[g[y], y]
```

yields

[image]

Let us now make an equation:

```
    eq = Inactivate[D[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, a[y], b[y]}], y], 
   D | Integrate] == D[g[y], y]
```

[image]

and solve it with respect to the integral in question:

[image]

Done. Have fun!